# Powershell-generated hash of directory doesn't match Linux-generated hash when directory is not-empty

Tags: powershell, checksum

I'm writing a Powershell script to compare the sha256 hash of a local Windows directory with the sha256 hash of a remote Linux directory...

```
$localHash_temp = (Get-ChildItem <local dir> -Exclude <excluded dir> -Recurse -File | Get-FileHash -Algorithm SHA256).Hash | Out-String
$localHash = (Get-FileHash -Algorithm SHA256 -InputStream ([IO.MemoryStream]::new([char[]]$localHash_temp))).Hash
$remoteHash_temp = ssh -i <rsa_key> <user>@<server> -q 'dir=<remote dir>; find "$dir" -type f -path <exclude dir> -prune -exec sha256sum {} \; | sed "s~$dir~~g" | LC_ALL=C sort -d | iconv -f UTF-8 -t UTF-16LE | sha256sum'
$remoteHash = $remoteHash_temp.TrimEnd("  -").ToUpper()

Write-Output $localHash
Write-Output $remoteHash
```

The interesting thing is when both directories are emtpy (minus the excluded directories), the hashes are identical...

```
E3B0C44298FC1C149AFBF4C8996FB92427AE41E4649B934CA495991B7852B855
E3B0C44298FC1C149AFBF4C8996FB92427AE41E4649B934CA495991B7852B855
```

However when I take a file and add it into both directories the hashes become different...

```
F65A82E42CE7C0B80EB4689F0E41291372C68F1F50CB929ACAFE839EC8E8638F
E3B0C44298FC1C149AFBF4C8996FB92427AE41E4649B934CA495991B7852B855
```

I'm not sure what the problem is. Any help is gladly appreciated.

Comment: Start by comparing the input before hashing. Linux shells work with text, Powershell with objects so maybe the string outputs do not match.